# Extra keys in export-csv in powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

I'm using `Get-ADUser` with `Filter` and `Properties` parameters to export all my users from the active directory and then export them to csv with `Export-Csv`. This adds five extra keys to the dictionary of each user.

```
'PSShowComputerName':'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection',
'WriteVerboseStream':'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection',
'WriteWarningStream':'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection',
'WriteDebugStream':'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection',
'WriteErrorStream':'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection'
```

While I'm just asking for the following properties:

```
CN, GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, Description, Created, WhenCreated, 
Enabled, LockedOut, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate, PasswordNeverExpires, 
CannotChangePassword, accountExpires, Initials, LogonHours
```

Why does it do that and how can I remove them?

Code:

```
$aduser = Get-ADUser `
            -Filter * `
            -Properties CN, GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, DistinguishedName, Description, Created, WhenCreated, 
                        Enabled, LockedOut, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate, PasswordNeverExpires, 
                        CannotChangePassword, accountExpires, Initials, LogonHours
$aduser | Export-Csv "E:\adusers.csv" -Encoding Unicode -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: We need to see the code you are using to generate this output in order to accurately answer this question since those are not AD attributes.

Comment: @Matt There is not much to it right now but sure I'll update my question wit the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the following you can manipulate the output as you see fit:

```
$aduser | Select DisplayName,Created,LockedOut | Export-Csv ".....
```

In the select part use can specify all the attributes you want and in the order you want!

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this before and didn't like how it would look like in the code but now that I think about it. Would the Select accept a list of strings?

Comment: Great, thanks. For some reason they are gone from my new file now (I have not added your answer yet). I'll add it just to be sure that they won't be in the output in the future.